Full model of gravitational waves?
Usually when we model gravitational waves use linearized gravity:
$$
g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}
$$
when applying this to the EFE and making some simplifications, when we solve we get a wave equation for the metric.
Although this might be insightful, this solution works as a description of waves that weren't generated by a source but rather were "already there".
This could be solved by finding the Green's functions for the linearized gravity, assuming the masses are point-like:
$$
\Box \bar h_{\mu \nu} = -2\kappa T_{\mu \nu}
$$
Still, this model is incomplete, because linearized gravity is just approximation. We should instead solve the full picture:
$$
R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu \nu} = \kappa T_{\mu \nu}
$$
where we assume that:
$$
T_{00} = m_1c \delta^{(4)}(x^\alpha - x^{\alpha'}) + m_2c \delta^{(4)}(x^\alpha - x^{\alpha''})
$$
where $x^{\alpha'}$ and  $x^{\alpha''}$
represents the position of the particles.
But those particles have to be affected by the metric itself via the geodesic equation. How would you solve this? Is this even possible? This full model of gravitational waves has a closed form solution? If the full picture is difficult to solve, there exists a solution for linearized gravity?

The answer is yes. Just use harmonic coordinates (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_coordinates). This is a rather common choice in numerical studies of GR.

@Jon While adopting harmonic coordinates can be very helpful, the act alone will not really answer the OP's question. In particular it tells you exactly nothing about how to include back-reaction.

That is exactly the reason why it is just a comment.

First of all there is no known closed-form solution for the two body problem in general relativity (except in some very specific edge cases). If you want to solve the full non-linear problem, you have to resort to numerical relativity and solve the equations numerically on a (super)computer. Note that in the full non-linear problem, you cannot have point particle sources, since this not compatible with general relativity. Hence you either need to have an addition model for the matter distribution, or your objects need to be black holes (which are technically vacuum solutions).
Alternatively, you can work iteratively.

You start with two point particles moving in Minkowski space.
You calculate the linear metric perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$ sourced by this matter distribution.
You can calculate the correction to the motion of the particles due to the presence of the metric perturbation.
Now you can calculate a second order metric perturbation sourced by the first order $h_{\mu\nu}$ and the corrected motion of the particles.
You repeat the last two steps as you please.

This, in a nutshell, described what is known as the post-Minkowskian expansion. In recent year this has been solved analytically up to fourth order, with some partial results at 5th order. However, because you started from the motion in Minkowski space this is mostly suited to describe the gravitational scattering of objects.
To describe the motion of two gravitationally bound objects. You typically need to additional expand the equations in a low velocity limit. This allows you to start from the solution of the Newtonian two body problem, and follow a similar iterative procedure, which leads to the so-called post-Newtonian expansion. For quasi-circular orbits this can be solve analytically up to 4.5PN order (i.e. corrections up to $(v/c)^9$ order). For more general orbits, you can only get partial closed form solutions at this order.
